# C# generics in a class inside a dictionary

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

I've got the following code:

```
protected Dictionary<string, ObjectAttribute<T>> attributes;
```

I should pass a generic type every time I add a new item to the directory, but I wouldn't like to use object/dynamic because it can cause some casting problems later on. So, is it possible to have it this way?

T is not defined in the class constructor or anywhere else, since I just need it every time I add an item.

Comment: 'T' must be replaced with a class name. You can be specific e.g. String, Integer … or general i.e. Object, or in-between Interface_that_all_other_classes_that_may_be_in_dictionary_inherit_from.

Comment: classes are generic: List<T> is a generic class, it is a class that can be of any type; You can not create a List<T>, or any generic type. List<string> and List<int> are types, they are no longer generic; You can create these.

Answer (score 5):

If you mean "and the `T` can change per item", then no: unless `ObjectAttribute` also has a non-generic base-class or implements a non-generic interface, i.e.

```
protected Dictionary<string, IObjectAttribute> attributes;
```

with

```
class ObjectAttribute<T> : IObjectAttribute {...}
```

would work.